# Changing view color using Delegation

Tags: swift, delegates, protocols

I have a UIView class ( delegator)  within a UIViewcontroller class . I need to change color of viewed view in the UIViewcontroller using protocol conformance from the UIViewcontroller. I have the protcol that takes the viewed view as a paramater just like how UITableviewdatasource has the number of rows that can be grabbed within the delegate

This is my whole code. Any help appreciated.

```
protocol uiviewdatasource: AnyObject {  
    func colorView ( using viewed: Viewed) -> UIColor
}

class Viewed: UIView {
     
    weak var colordatasource: uiviewdatasource?

    // i need to create some function to call this delegate 
    

}





class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    let tableview = UITableView()
    
    let viewed = Viewed() // I need to change background color of  this viewed view 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        view.addSubview(viewed)
        
        viewed.colordatasource = self
        viewed.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        
            self.viewed.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 10),
            self.viewed.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -10),
            self.viewed.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 10),
            self.viewed.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -10),
        ])
        
        viewed.layer.borderWidth = 2
        viewed.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        viewed.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    }


}



extension ViewController: uiviewdatasource  {
    func colorView(using viewed: Viewed) -> UIColor {
        return .magenta // i need the magenta to be background color of the  viewed view
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: What's supposed to call the `colorView(using:)` method?

Comment: Unrelated but you may wish to use standard naming conventions. Class, struct, enum, and protocol names should start with uppercase letters. You should also use camelCase for naming things. `uiviewdatasource` should be `UIViewDataSource`. `colordatasource` should be `colorDataSource`.

Comment: I need to change the view viewed background color using the using color parameter of the protocol function  like how

 func tableView(
    _ tableView: UITableView,
    numberOfRowsInSection section: Int
) -> Int

changes number of rows in the tableview

Comment: Something needs to call the `colorView(using:)` method. With a `UITableView`, it is the table view that calls all of the data source and delegate methods. It's unclear in your code what is supposed to call your data source method and when. Presumably some code in your `Viewed` class needs to call the data source method. But you don't show any of that code.

Comment: it is calling the  viewed.colordatasource = self in the view controller